# Cloudwatch logs insight coalesce on concat output

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have the following query on cloudwatch logs

```
fields replace(path,'%20',' ') as pathz
|parse pathz /^(?<url1>.*) [!A-Z0-9-]*(?<url2>[ˆ!].*)$/ 
| fields  concat(url1, url2) as url
| display coalesce(url,pathz) as furl
```

3 sample pathz parsed are:

```
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/v1/assignments/ASSIGN-WORKLIST GNR-AUTO-WORK ST-4102!RACCOLTADATIPRELIMINARI_FLOW
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/DeviceInfoPackage/v1/SetInitialCaseInfomation
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/v1/cases/GNR-AUTO-WORK 43FFC9776C00474388A664A8A3E24B68
```

The desired output is removing the data:

```
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/v1/assignments/ASSIGN-WORKLIST GNR-AUTO-WORK RACCOLTADATIPRELIMINARI_FLOW
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/DeviceInfoPackage/v1/SetInitialCaseInfomation
/v1/routing/pega-public/prweb/api/v1/cases/GNR-AUTO-WORK
```

but I can't manage to get it

Third line is empty
this is because concat output doesn't return 'null' which could be skipped by coalesce
but it returns an empty string that is matched

I digged in the doc and in few examples on the internet but there is no way to get this working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved with this:

```
fields @timestamp, status, replace(path,'%20',' ') as pathx
|parse pathx /(?<a1>^[^ ]+ *[A-Z-]*)( (?<a2>[A-Z0-9-]+){1,2}(?<a3>.*))*/
|filter 
|display concat(a1,a3) as cleanurl
```